# Make text box appear to the right of wrapper/clip-path

Tags: html, css

I have based my code out of this CSS Shapes Layout Pyramid from codepen: https://codepen.io/s-gupta/pen/jOMGbMX

I'm quite happy with the shape of my pyramid, but I also want a text box to appear to the right of each pyramid step when you hover over the element. I based my text box code on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

However, as you see, the text box appears within the wrapper/pyramid, not outside of it. The text in the text box will be quite long, so it cannot be within the pyramid.
How can I make it go outside (and preferably to the right of the pyramid) ?

I'm quite new to CSS/HTML, but I'm trying to learn - Hope somebody out there can help me :)

```css
body {
  /*background: #333;
  font-family: "SF UI Text", "Avenir", "Helvetica", arial, san-serif;
  color: #888;*/
}


.wrapper {
  margin: 5vh auto 0;
}

.pyramid {
  float: left;
  shape-outside:polygon(310px 0px, 130px 405px, 558px 405px);
  padding-right:60px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
}
.zone {
  padding:40px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  color: black;
  background-blend-mode:darken;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.zone:nth-child(1){
   background:rgba(248,153,46); /* url("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/05/13/34/laugenbrotchen-1122509_960_720.jpg") center / cover;*/
  width: 20%;
  clip-path:url("#part1");
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0%,0%,100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  /*-webkit-clip-path:polygon(50% 0%,100% 100%, 0% 100%);*/
   
}
.zone:nth-child(2){ background:rgba(248,153,46); 
  width: 40%;
  clip-path:url("#part2");
  clip-path:polygon(40% 0%,0%,60% 0, 100% 100%,0% 100%);
  /*-webkit-clip-path:polygon(25% 0%,75% 0, 100% 100%,0% 100%);*/
}
.zone:nth-child(3){
  width: 60%;
  background:rgba(248,153,46); 
  clip-path:url("#part3");
  clip-path:polygon(30% 0,0%, 70% 0, 100% 100%,0% 100%);
  /*-webkit-clip-path:polygon(16.5% 0, 83% 0, 100% 100%,0% 100%);*/
}
.zone:nth-child(4){
  background:rgba(248,153,46); 
  width: 80%;
  clip-path:url("#part4");
  clip-path:polygon(20% 0, 0%,80% 0, 100% 100%,0% 100%);
  /*-webkit-clip-path:polygon(12.5% 0,87.5% 0, 100% 100%,0% 100%);*/
}
.zone:nth-child(5){
  background:rgba(248,153,46); 
  width: 100%;
  clip-path:url("#part5");
  clip-path:polygon(10% 0, 0%,100% 0, 100% 100%,0% 100%);
  /*-webkit-clip-path:polygon(12.5% 0,87.5% 0, 100% 100%,0% 100%);*/
}
/*.zone:hover {
  background-color: rgba(118,113,113);
  color: white;
}
*/
.zone .arrowtext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 105%;
}

.zone .arrowtext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%; /* To the left of the tooltip */
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}

.zone:hover {
  background-color: rgba(118,113,113);
  color: white;
}

.zone:hover .arrowtext{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pyramid">
    <div class="zone">0. zero
   <span class="arrowtext">Tooltip text</span></div>
    <div class="zone">1. One</div>
    <div class="zone">2. Two</div>
    <div class="zone">3. Three</div>
    <div class="zone">4. Four</div>
  </div>
  
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
   <clipPath id="part1" clipPathUnits= "objectBoundingBox">
     <polygon points= "0.5 0, 1 1, 0 1"/>
   </clipPath>
   <clipPath id="part2" clipPathUnits= "objectBoundingBox">
     <polygon points= "0.25 0,0.75 0, 1 1, 0 1"/>
   </clipPath>
   <clipPath id="part3" clipPathUnits= "objectBoundingBox">
     <polygon points= "0.165 0,0.83 0, 1 1, 0 1"/>
   </clipPath>
   <clipPath id="part4" clipPathUnits= "objectBoundingBox">
     <polygon points= "0.125 0,0.875 0, 1 1, 0 1"/>
   </clipPath>
   <clipPath id="part5" clipPathUnits= "objectBoundingBox">
     <polygon points= "0.1 0,0.9 0, 1 1, 0 1"/>
   </clipPath>
     </defs>
</svg>
```

And further, how could I make the `arrowtext` go over several sentences? I figured I can make the width wider and reduce the `clip path` so that the triangle takes up less of the area. That solves the problem of making whole 1-2 lines visible, but what about getting text that goes over 2 lines? I've tried `z-index` for example, but does not work. In other words I'm looking for a way to make the text expand further than only the height of the *hovered element* or `zone`.

[image: make text expand further than only height of the hovered element]

Comment: *without having to restructure the whole code?* --> you can have an easier and simpler and shorter code than what you have and fix your issue at the same time

Comment: @TemaniAfif that would be even better of course! You're right, I could've worded myself a bit better.

Comment: so remove that requirement from your question if you want people to give better solution otherwise many will not want to fix the existing code

Comment: I reworded it now, thanks for your feedback @TemaniAfif.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version where I am reducing the size for the sake of the demo (feel free to update them).

The trick is to create triangle shapes using pseudo element on each "zone" element. By making them relative to "pyramid" they will overlap (creating the illusion of only one). Then by using `clip-path:inset(0)` on "zone" each one will show one portion on the triangle.

```css
.pyramid {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative; /* relative on "pyramid" and not "zone" */
}
/* build the triangle as pseudo element fo "zone" */
.zone:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: rgba(248, 153, 46);
  /* the pyramid shape */
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.zone {
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  clip-path: inset(0); /* clip the triangle to only the shape of each "zone"*/
}
/* using an extra div to correctly place the tooltip*/
.zone > div {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
/* update color on hover */
.zone:hover {
  color: white;
}
.zone:hover:before {
  background: rgba(118, 113, 113);
}
/**/

.zone .arrowtext {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 105%;
}

.zone:hover .arrowtext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid">
  <div class="zone">
    <div>0. zero<span class="arrowtext">Tooltip text</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="zone">1. One</div>
  <div class="zone">2. Two</div>
  <div class="zone">3. Three</div>
  <div class="zone">4. Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, great @TemaniAfif , that's great. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the much better code @temani- Please see additional edit at the end of  my question if you have time and know how I could make it work to make the ```arrowtext``` expand over several lines.

Comment: @RamyPanda remove the white-space:nowrap

Comment: I wished it would work @Temani, but it doesn't unfortunately. Removing the ```white-space```and for example increasing the ```width``` makes the text box wider, but the ```height``` doesn't go below the zone area even though I try increasing the ```height```, ```z-index``` and so on.